# Create triangles from points on ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, grids-graticules, mesh

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.

I need to create a grid where all the points are vertexes of triangles that do not overlap themselves. 
I want this to be done by only using the points location, no elevation or any 3D data. Just a plain polyline. Is this possible?

Comment: One polyline, polylines, polygons?

Comment: And I don't mind the output, I just need the triangles delineated

Comment: What error do you get using TIN?

Comment: Whether if I use the default height or a field with actual values on Height Field, the created field doesn't display on the map. so it's not an "error" in execution, more like I cannot see the results but it seems as if there are some

Answer (score 3):

The TIN tools in ArcGIS should work as they produce Delaunay triangulation.  You may have to fake a height field - if using the same height everywhere causes Arc to get 'clever' and give you odd results, you can use any random height and then smash the result in the z plane (export the TIN to triangles using the TIN Polygon tool and save as a 2D shapefile).

If you are really stuck, grab a copy of QGIS and just run it's Delaunay triangulation algorithm from the Processing Toolbox - That does exactly what you want without any fuss or cost.  You can also find the tool by going `Vector->Geometry Tools->Delaunay triangulation` (there is another one available via GRASS too v.delaunay)

Comment: I tried faking a height by using a field on "Height Field" that actually has values but still I'm unable to see results. I am really stuck but I am really need it to work on ArcGIS since I want to add this process to Model Builder

Comment: Did you set the spatial reference?

Comment: Is that the coordinate system?

Comment: If you set the default height for each point as say 10 then create the TIN, the default symbology ArcGIS presents is white so wouldn't be immediately visible in the map view. I tested this and got 9 classes in the symbology with the white one being on top so displaying first.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said no elevation but couldnt you use TIN and then export the subsequent features as polylines? Or even copy and paste them into an empty ployline feature class.

Comment: it sounds reasonable but I haven't been able to make it work so far

Comment: How does this fail?

Comment: The TIN can be created but it doesn't display on the map. It seems as if there should be results, but I can't see any

Comment: Have you tried to convert your shapefile to a geodatabase feature class and export the results there?

Comment: I can't export the TIN results, I'm not getting that option

Comment: Hmm even from a FIle Geodatabase feature class? Are you running a Model to test this possible solution? If so may need to save the results out as a Feature layer...

Comment: Do you have 3D or Spatial Analyst? I know you can with 3D Analyst, looks like there may be a way with Spatial Analyst